# Removing all non digits from a list

Tags: python

After reading from a file I have a list of lists contaning not only digits but also other characters, which I would like to get rid of.

I've tried using re.sub function but this doesn't seem to work

```
import re     


Poly_id= [['0', '[4', '8', '18', '20', '5', '0', '4]'], ['1', '[13', '16', 
'6', '11', '13]'], ['2', '[3', '1', '10', '9', '2', '15', '3]'], ['3', 
'[13', '12', '16', '13]'], ['4', '[13', '11', '17', '14', '7', '13]']]

for x in Poly_id:
    [re.sub(r'\W', '', ch) for ch in x]
```

This doesn't seem to change a thing in this list.

I would like to have a list with only numbers as elements so that I could convert them into integers

Comment: You don't need `re` for this.  But your lists of lists doesn't contain any non digits... Please provide a more useful example.

Comment: Common mistake: `re.sub` does not mutate its argument but rather returns a new string in which the substitution was applied.

Comment: `[re.sub(r'\W', '', ch) for ch in x]` only return a new list. it won't change the old one.

Comment: [Remove non numeric values from list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881995/remove-non-numeric-values-from-list-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess technically `[4` is non numeric so you can do something like this:

```
Poly_id = [[char for char in _list if str.isnumeric(char)] for _list in Poly_id]
```

**Output:**

```
['0', '8', '18', '20', '5', '0']
['1', '16', '6', '11']
['2', '1', '10', '9', '2', '15']
['3', '12', '16']
['4', '11', '17', '14', '7']
```

If you just want to remove the non numeric values and not the complete entry then you can do this:

```
Poly_id = [[''.join(char for char in substring if str.isnumeric(char)) for substring in _list] for _list in Poly_id]
```

**Output:**

```
['0', '4', '8', '18', '20', '5', '0', '4']
['1', '13', '16', '6', '11', '13']
['2', '3', '1', '10', '9', '2', '15', '3']
['3', '13', '12', '16', '13']
['4', '13', '11', '17', '14', '7', '13']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution if you want to get rid of the `'['` in `'[4'` but keep the `'4'`:

```
res = [[re.sub(r'\W', '', st) for st in inlist] for inlist in Poly_id]
```

`res` is:

```
[
 ['0', '4', '8', '18', '20', '5', '0', '4'],
 ['1', '13', '16', '6', '11', '13'],
 ['2', '3', '1', '10', '9', '2', '15', '3'],
 ['3', '13', '12', '16', '13'],
 ['4', '13', '11', '17', '14', '7', '13']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module, "itertools"

```
import itertools

list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(list(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists)))

>>>[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I don't think that's a case here, I don't have  a nested list which I would like to unnest, but rather list with some elements that I would like to modify